# Add leading zeroes/0's to existing Excel values to certain length

Tags: excel, padding

There are many, many questions and quality answers on SO regarding how to prevent leading zeroes from getting stripped when importing to or exporting from Excel.  However, I already have a spreadsheet that has values in it that were truncated as numbers when, in fact, they should have been handled as strings.  I need to clean up the data and add the leading zeros back in.

There is a field that should be four characters with lead zeros padding out the string to four characters.  However:

```
"23" should be "0023", 
"245" should be "0245", and
"3829" should remain "3829"
```

Question: Is there an Excel formula to pad these 0's back onto these values so that they are all four characters?

Note: this is similar to the age old Zip Code problem where New England-area zip codes get their leading zero dropped and you have to add them back in.

Comment: Is the period supposed to be there in `"3829."`?

Comment: No, but that is the proper position for a "." character in the sentence according to my trusty copy of Strunk & White.  Removed it for clarity.

Comment: I’d accept that except that it was in a code block, in which I tend to take things more literally. (Also, Excel stores every number as a float, so that could have been a decimal place.)

Comment: @josh upvote for correctly spelling "accept that except that".

Answer (score 553, accepted):

```
=TEXT(A1,"0000")
```

However the [TEXT function](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx) is able to do other fancy stuff like date formating, aswell.

Comment: OMG! Perfect!  You learn something new every single day.  I even have multiple dog-eared Excel books and never came across this -- will use anytime I have mangled Excel-based zip code data in the future.

Comment: This works well with decimal numbers... but what about hexadecimal? I can't find a way to make leading 0s work with it...

Comment: @shadow Hexadecimal number for Excel is a string, not a number. So handle it as a string: `=RIGHT("0000" + A1, 4)`.

Comment: +1 Amazing :D Thanks for that. My only problem is it will truncate if the hex number is bigger than 4 digits, but that's not a problem in my case.

Comment: Wow, this is great.  Do you happen to know how Excel implements this behind the scenes?

Comment: @shadow, [DEC2HEX](http://www.excelnuggets.com/Engineering/Functions/DEC2HEX) takes a places argument.  So `=DEC2HEX(HEX2DEC(A1),4)` works well to pad hex numbers.

Comment: The provided solution works it is just that in version of office 2k13, they changed the syntax of TEXT function. it should be `=TEXT(A3;"0000000")`

Comment: @mcs They did not change the syntax. Your version of Excel [happens to use `;`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2853427) as the parameter separator, which it takes from your Windows language settings.

Comment: Good stuff, GSerg & Raz!

Comment: Thanks Raz, that last suggestion of yours did the trick for me.

Answer (score 82):

The more efficient (less obtrusive) way of doing this is through custom formatting.

1. Highlight the column/array you want to style.
2. Click <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> or Format -> Format Cells.
3. In the Number tab, choose Custom.
4. Set the Custom formatting to 000#. (zero zero zero #)

Note that this does not actually change the value of the cell.  It only displays the leading zeroes in the worksheet.

Comment: This works great if there is no need to retain the leading zeroes past the original cell but won't work if the strings need to be used anywhere else. It would make the cells display as 0004, 01032, 0284 but if you tried to combine the strings in a separate cell it would show, for example, 4-1032-284 instead of the desired 0004-01032-0284

Comment: @AshtonSheets yes, as I noted in the answer it only displays the leading zeroes, it does nothing to the actual value. However, there have been situations where I used this instead of `=text()` because of its convenience and lack of formula involved.

Comment: For reference, this should actually be `0000`, not `000#`. Otherwise it doesn't work for 0.

Comment: I use a variation of this solution to round to millions of dollars: $#,,"M" However this turns $200,000 into $.2M when I would prefer $0.2M. Then I use $0#,,"M" and it gives me my $0.2M format but also changes numbers larger than 1,000,000 into $01.0M format! I seem to be going in circles - is there a solution for getting a 0 before the . ?

Comment: For those with my issue above, the answer was to swap out # (hash) for 0 (zero). The # gives you no character when there's no value but the 0 gives you a zero when there's no value! Makes sense and works great: $0.0,,"M"

Comment: Also did not work for me using 000# but worked when I just specified custom format as 0000 for a four digit number, 00000 for five, 000000 for six etc. Obviously this is only helpful for shorter format numbers

Answer (score 16):

I hit this page trying to pad hexadecimal values when I realized that `DEC2HEX()` provides that very feature *for free*.
You just need to add a second parameter. For example, tying to turn `12` into `0C`
`DEC2HEX(12,2)` => `0C`
`DEC2HEX(12,4)` => `000C`
... and so on

Answer (score 15):

I know this was answered a while ago but just chiming with a simple solution here that I am surprised wasn't mentioned.

```
=RIGHT("0000" & A1, 4)
```

Whenever I need to pad I use something like the above.  Personally I find it the simplest solution and easier to read.

Comment: This worked great for padding raw text, which in my case was a hexadecimal number.

Comment: shouldn't it be `=RIGHT("0000" & A1; 4)` ?

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure if this is new in Excel 2013, but if you right-click on the column and say "Special" there is actually a pre-defined option for ZIP Code and ZIP Code + 4.  Magic.

[image]

Comment: Great suggestion and update.  Need to give Microsoft a -1 for encouraging anyone to store SSNs in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you use custom formatting and need to concatenate those values elsewhere, you can copy them and Paste Special --> Values elsewhere in the sheet (or on a different sheet), then concatenate those values.

Answer (score 1):

Even this will work nicely

```
REPT(0,2-LEN(F2)&F2
```

where 2 is total number of digits, for 0 ~ 9 -> it will display 00 to 09 rest nothing will be added.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the number you want to pad is in cell A1, and the "padding number of zeros" is 4 ,

e.g.

> "23" should be "0023",
> "245" should be "0245", and
> "3829" should remain "3829"

then

```
=TEXT(A1,REPT("0",4))
```