# Extending a binary number to 32 bits in text

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have this number

```
111100000000000010001000
```

I want to extend it to 32 bits with leading zeros. In other words:

```
00000000111100000000000010001000
```

So I found this suggestion here:
[Add leading zeroes/0's to existing Excel values to certain length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992541/add-leading-zeroes-0s-to-existing-excel-values-to-certain-length)

is to use the Right function. So I do:

```
=RIGHT("00000000000000000000000000000000"+A1,32)
```

I end up getting a number in Engineering notation. So as suggested somewhere else I add:

```
=TEXT(RIGHT("00000000000000000000000000000000"+A1,32), "0")
```

I still get

```
111100000000000000000000
```

Not 32-bit and the trailing 10001000 has become zeros.

Any idea what's happening here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel takes that as a decimal number, not a binary number.

`111100000000000010001000` as a decimal number is too much for the number precision Excel has to offer, so that is rounded to `111100000000000000000000` before you apply your zeros (which you can see yourself if you apply a numeric format to `A1` that disallows scientific notation).

The solution is the same, treat all numbers as string. Prefix the source number in `A1` with an apostrophe to make it a string, the `RIGHT` will then work as you expect.
Well, it actually won't, because [I used `+`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992541/add-leading-zeroes-0s-to-existing-excel-values-to-certain-length#comment18519598_3992588) when I should have used `&`, so Excel will try to convert to numbers and actually make the addition. So correct the formula:

```
=RIGHT("00000000000000000000000000000000"&A1,32)
```

Comment: Sorry but that didn't work. Have you tried it yourself?
Update: Apologies, that actually did work. Adding the & was all that was needed.