# putting digit between digits in Excel

Tags: excel

In my country any bank account number has a secondary key which named SHEBA, and there is formula to calculate the SHEBA from account number.

For example if my account number is `801-800-125954-1`, the SHEBA of this number is IR0008010080000125954001.

As you can see, changing the account number to SHEBA has been done by putting a handful of zero between account number's digits (however It's not always so simple).

So, I want write formula in Excel that can put zero - or any other digit - between our Number of customer accounts.
I mean, write function in which it's input is a number and output is same number plus some another digit between number

Answer (score 0):

If you can [split your string after each '`-`'](https://superuser.com/a/483422), you can pad each one with the appropriatz number of '0'.
Se "[Add leading zeroes/0's to existing Excel values to certain length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3992588/6309)" ([using TEXT](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/text.php))

`801` would become `"IR"+TEXT("800","000000")`

[image: http://jasonwhurley.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/padnumbertoleft.jpg?w=595]

Answer (score 0):

Since you only posted one number and one SHEBA, it is a bit hard to establish a pattern, especially if, as you say "It's not always so simple".

You can use one formula to get from your number to your SHEBA

```
="IR000"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","00")
```

[image]