# Leading 0 is trimmed from the excel php

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am trying a lot to include the leading 0 in the excel which is getting trimmed from the excel sheet.
  I used like below for the column value and it is showing the leading 0, but with a single quote at the begining.

The value i am using like  "'$value"

Can anyone please help me in this how to remove this single quote from the excel with having the leading 0?

Comment: Code please.
(a) What kind of file format are you dealing with in Excel - csv or xls/xlsx?
(b) What kind of data are you dealing with? Same number of digits or variable?

Comment: The file format is xlsx.It  is string format data with 10 digits.But its trimmimg the leading 0 from it.

Comment: There are lots of questions already on SO about this. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3992541/4606130 for example. Search "excel leading zero" and you will see what I mean. Please Search before you post.

Comment: I got the answer.Thanks for the reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend formatting the data range as a 10 digit number instead of inserting an `'`.

You can find out more about `Range.NumberFormat` [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx).

Where `$value` is your value and `$worksheet` is a [Worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194464.aspx):

```
$value = "0000000001"
$workSheet.Range("A1").Value2 = $value
$workSheet.Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0000000000"
```

[image: Output in Excel]