# EXCEL - how to format a row to contains zeros before the actual number

Tags: excel-formula

Trying to add some number in an Excel sheet... the number must be with a zero bero but somehow my Excel skills are not very up to date.

The numbers must be (see below) -000058 instead of "58" is there a smart way to solve the .

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Best regards from Kvolle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add leading zeroes/0's to existing Excel values to certain length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992541/add-leading-zeroes-0s-to-existing-excel-values-to-certain-length)

Comment: If you're typing in the values manually, you can just add an apostrophe in front of the number like `'000058`, which will then show the value exactly how you want it to look...

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:

Found the answer on : 
[https://www.google.dk/imgres?imgurl=https://cdn.ablebits.com/*img-blog/leading-zeros/add-leading-zeros-excel.png&imgrefurl=https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/01/18/add-leading-zeros-excel/&h=618&w=541&tbnid=MAu0QGAgn9h6sM:&q=excel+display+leading+zeros&tbnh=160&tbnw=140&usg=AI4*-kSnyAFDtM74t5dexBYAiWZnjvi-cA&vet=12ahUKEwiSu9iXzoPfAhXHECwKHQS6CXcQ9QEwAHoECAcQBg..i&docid=qOCHc5gsYCLWnM&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSu9iXzoPfAhXHECwKHQS6CXcQ9QEwAHoECAcQBg](https://www.google.dk/imgres?imgurl=https://cdn.ablebits.com/_img-blog/leading-zeros/add-leading-zeros-excel.png&imgrefurl=https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/01/18/add-leading-zeros-excel/&h=618&w=541&tbnid=MAu0QGAgn9h6sM:&q=excel+display+leading+zeros&tbnh=160&tbnw=140&usg=AI4_-kSnyAFDtM74t5dexBYAiWZnjvi-cA&vet=12ahUKEwiSu9iXzoPfAhXHECwKHQS6CXcQ9QEwAHoECAcQBg..i&docid=qOCHc5gsYCLWnM&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSu9iXzoPfAhXHECwKHQS6CXcQ9QEwAHoECAcQBg)

[image]