# How to format text data to have 6 characters by adding zeros?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to format text in cells (excel) that has 2-3 characters (both letters and numbers) to a new cell but the data to have be 6 characters long. I want to add zeros infront of the data.
ex. im45 -> 00im45 456->000456 4d4e-> 004d4e id->0000id

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/q/3992541/4961700

Answer (score 2):

lets assume your data starts in B2.  Add six 0 to the front of the value of the cell as text and then take the right most 6 characters.  This can be done using hte following formula:

```
=RIGHT("000000"&B2,6)
```

If you needed more than 6 characters you might want to look into the REPT function.