# How to convert number to string with zeros in front in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, format

I need to convert number to string that have zeros in front because I have to report it on an Excel sheet, with vbscript language.
iF i use the function Cstr, the zeros are removed

```vb
objtemp.setvar "num_code", rs("code")
```

It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate ("&") a sequence of "0"s and your number, take the right part:

```
>> SetLocale "en_us"
>> For Each n In Array(4711, 47.11, "123", 0)
>>     WScript.Echo Right(String(10, "0") & n, 10)
>> Next
>>
0000004711
0000047.11
0000000123
0000000000
```

To force Excel to treat the data as String, format the column/cell as Text and/or prepend a '.

Comment: I try but it doesn't work when I put the data in the excel sheet

Comment: @lucamontessori maybe next time explain you are trying to format the value in Excel. This method works in VBScript which is what the question asked for.

Comment: @lucamontessori relevant https://stackoverflow.com/q/3992541/692942